# Is there a way to compare all the titles of all Rss feeds and delete duplicates?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm wondering if there is a way to compare ALL TITLES in ALL RSS FEEDS and delete the duplicates.

I read through a lot of RSS Feeds, and it's obvious that a lot of people cross-post to several forums, and then I end up seeing the same RSS Feed multiple times.

I really just want to see each one one single time.  Is there a way to list all feeds, and delete duplicates, if I actually have duplicates in my entire MS Outlook RSS Feed list?

Here's 0m3r's script, modified slightly.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim RSS_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Items As Items
Dim DupItem As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For j = 1 To 21
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set RSS_Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds).Folders(j)

    Set DupItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Items = RSS_Folder.Items

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is PostItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            If DupItem.Exists(Item.Subject) Then
                Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
                Debug.Print TypeName(Item) ' Print on Immediate Window
                Item.Delete
            Else
                'Debug.Print Item.Subject
                DupItem.Add Item.Subject, 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print RSS_Folder
Next j

Set olNs = Nothing
Set RSS_Folder = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing
Set Items = Nothing
Set DupItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Work with [**Dictionary Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) to compare  `Items.Subject` in your `olFolderRssFeeds`*

---

> *<sub>**[Dictionary in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)** is a collection-object: 
>   you can store all kinds of things in it: numbers, texts, dates, arrays, ranges, variables and objects, Every item in a Dictionary gets its own unique key and 
>   With that key you can get direct access to the item (reading/writing).</sub>*

---

*Here is quick Example code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim RSS_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Items As Items
    Dim DupItem As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set RSS_Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds) _
                         .Folders("Microsoft At Home")

    Set DupItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Items = RSS_Folder.Items

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is PostItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            If DupItem.Exists(Item.subject) Then
                Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window
                Debug.Print TypeName(Item) ' Print on Immediate Window
'               Item.Delete
            Else
                DupItem.Add Item.subject, 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set RSS_Folder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set DupItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

*This Example shows how to process all Folders under **RSS Feed** Folders*

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DupeRSS()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim RSS_Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set RSS_Folder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)

'   // Process Current Folder
    Example RSS_Folder
End Sub
Public Sub Example(ByVal ParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim DupItem As Object
    Dim Items As Items
    Dim i As Long

    Set DupItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Items = ParentFolder.Items

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is PostItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            If DupItem.Exists(Item.subject) Then
                Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window
                Debug.Print TypeName(Item) ' Print on Immediate Window
                Item.Delete
            Else
                DupItem.Add Item.subject, 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i

'   // Recurse through subfolders
    If ParentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Folder In ParentFolder.Folders
            Example Folder
            Debug.Print Folder.Name
        Next
    End If

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set DupItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Remember the code will only compare duplicate in single folder*

Comment: Thanks 0m3r!  I modified your script slightly, and updated my OP.  For some reason, I'm not deleting the dupes, and I know there are several dupes.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with the For j = 1 to 21 ... Next j.  I'm trying to loop through 21 RSS feeds and compare all subjects to each other.

Comment: I have 21 Rss feeds.  I just posted an image.  When I start looping through each, the RSS_Folder name appears to be referenced correctly.

Comment: No, I guess you didn't see my last comment.  The thread doesn't seem to be going in chronological order.  Anyway, but it's still not deleting dupes. I added a couple lines of code to your script to confirm it; I wrote all instances of 'Item.Subject' to a text file, since I could only see 200 at a time in the Immediate Window.  I'm dumping everything to a text file and I see 196 dupes. n = FreeFile() strFile_Path = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test.txt" Open strFile_Path For Append As #1 ' other VBA here... Write #1, Item.Subject Close #n

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea.

```
 For Each myItem In subFolder.Items
    If InStr(myItem.Subject, "[on hold]") > 0 Then
```

You can use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to find all items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful.

The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- Finally, you can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about that in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not deleting dupes.  I added a couple lines of code to your script to confirm it; I'm dumping everything to a text file and I see 196 dupes.  

    n = FreeFile()
    strFile_Path = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test.txt"
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    ' other VBA here...
    Write #1, Item.Subject
Close #n

Comment: Thanks for all the help 0m3r.  Is there a final solution for this?  What I'm looking at now still does not work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Again,  0m3r, this doesn't yet work for me.  You seem to know this stuff pretty well.  Can you please post back with a working solution?  Thanks!!